# C++- If statement issue. Code will not run the else or else if

Tags: c++, if-statement

I will enter my code below. As a disclaimer I am a complete and utter novice, i know my code is terribly laid out ect and I should be creating functions... For now I'm keeping it simple.

My problem is that my if statement will run the "if" part, but it will not run the "else if" part. Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
// Coding Challenges.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console 
application.
//
#include "cstdlib"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char responses(char user_response)
{
return user_response;
}

int main()
{
char responses;
char user_response;
cout << "Welcome to the tempature conversion program." << endl;
cout << "Please type F to convert from farenheit to celcius or C for celcius 
to farenheit." << endl;
//getchar(user_response);
cin >> user_response;
getchar();
cout << "You entered: " <<user_response << endl;


switch (user_response) {
case 'F':
    cout << "You have chosen to convert from farenheit to celcius." << endl;
    break;

case 'C':
    cout << "You have chosen to convert from celcius to farenheit." << endl;
    break;

default:
    cout << "Woops. It Looks like you haven't entered correctly." << endl;
    break;
}
getchar();
cout << "Code should have ran " << endl;
getchar();
cout << "You entered: " << user_response << endl;
getchar();

if (user_response = 'F') {
    double f_val = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the value of farenheit you would like to convert: 
" << endl;
    cin >> f_val;
    cout << f_val;
    getchar();
    getchar();


} else if (user_response = 'C') {
    double c_val = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the value of celcius you would like to convert: " 
<< endl;
    cin >> c_val;
    cout << c_val;
    getchar();
    getchar();


} else {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    return 0;
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
getchar();
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Ignore any code i have obviously used for testing/ debugging.

Thanks,

Ted

Comment: `user_response = 'F'` should be `user_response == 'F'` otherwise you are doing an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: btw using functions is one way to keep it simple. It is much easier to reason 10 times about 10 lines of code compared to one block of 100 lines

Comment: This is definitely 'achievement unlocked'. Everyone has to make that mistake a few times! `=` is assignment `==` is comparison but both can appear in `if` condition but have very different behaviours.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing `user_response` with any character there, as you are using the assignment operator (=) and not the equal comparison one (==). So you are always entering your first condition, as you are just testing if `user_response` is different to 0, which is the case as you just assigned "F" to it. You have to use == and not = when testing a value.

```
if (user_response == 'F') { // == operator there, and not =
    double f_val = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the value of farenheit you would like to convert: 
" << endl;
    cin >> f_val;
    cout << f_val;
    getchar();
    getchar();


} else if (user_response == 'C') { // Same there
    double c_val = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the value of celcius you would like to convert: " 
<< endl;
    cin >> c_val;
    cout << c_val;
    getchar();
    getchar();


} else {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    return 0;
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
if (user_response = 'F') {
```

is equivalent to

```
user_response = 'F';
if (user_response) {
```

which is equivalent to

```
user_response = 'F';
if (user_response != 0) {
```

As you just set `user_response` to 'F' it obviously is not 0, so you always get the if-path.

If you want to compare you need to write

```
if (user_response == 'F') {
```

Depending on the compiler you can catch those errors by setting up the compiler's warning Level (always a good idea) and reading the warnings carefully.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! That fixed it. I should probably get to know the operators for cpp... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comaring but assigning here:

```
if (user_response = 'F')
                  ^------ This is assignment
                  v------ This is comparison
if (user_response == 'F')
```

The value of the assignment is something that can be converted to a `bool` and yields true. Most compilers issue a warning for this. The way to catch such typos with a compiler error is to write it like this:

```
    if ('F' = user_response)   //  -> compiler error !!
    if ('F' == user_response)  //  -> ok
```